# How to have child processes return values to the parent

Tags: php, multiprocessing, shared-memory, pcntl

I'm trying to run a for loop across multiple processes, and need each of the for loops to write to an array in the parent process. I've tried exiting the child process with an array, but `pcntl_wexitstatus()` can only return an integer. And so I'm stuck.

I'm very new to multiprocessing, however, I've seen people say that a good solution to sharing variables between parent and child is `shmop`, but I don't really know how to utilize it.

Here's my code:

```
$output = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    $start = ($i == 0) ? 1 : (1000000 * $i) + 1;
    $end = 1000000 * ($i + 1);

    if (!$pid) {
        for ($run = $start; $run <= $end; $run++) {
            $output[$i][] = 'Run ' . $run;
        }

        exit($i);
    }
}

while (pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1) {
    $status = pcntl_wexitstatus($status);
}

echo implode("\n", $output);
```

Just to clarify what I expect to happen, the `$output` array should contain four items which are also arrays with one million items each. It should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Run 1
            [1] => Run 2
            [2] => Run 3
            ...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Run 1000001
            [1] => Run 1000002
            [2] => Run 1000003
            ...
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Run 2000001
            [1] => Run 2000002
            [2] => Run 2000003
            ...
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Run 3000001
            [1] => Run 3000002
            [2] => Run 3000003
            ...
        )

)
```

Comment: I'd focus on what you're trying to do and how you're trying to achieve it. Personally, I'd go with threads in your case, not processes since you need to share data between execution units. Another form of "sharing" the data between processes could be a centralized database, where each process would write before they exit. Signal caught by the parent would make it read from such a database. It's not the fastest solution, but it does work. However, take a look at http://www.php.net/pthreads

Answer (score 0):

Php fork (like fork in NIX) this is only full copy of process and her env. Parent process not known of changes in children. And children cant pass results to parent. Parent can only check for end of children processes. If you want pass data you can use shared memory. But attention! Shared memory in php this is not real (OS) shared memory. But for php it works.

You can find solutions here: https://github.com/search?q=php+fork

Comment: not true, you can also use messages or use pipes